# How to separate a line into different variables in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++ and programming in general and I would like to know if there is a way to separate a line from a text file into different variables. For example, I want to separate this:

```
GreenTea limited 24 Instock
```

And assign each word/number into different variables:

```
string product;
string type;
int code;
string availability;
```

How can I achieve this easily? I've used a for loop so that I can find a space and take the substring of the word in order to separate it, but this seems highly inefficient and time consuming.

Comment: `std::istringstream ss("GreenTea limited 24 Instock"); ss >> product >> type >> code >> availability;`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c

Comment: I mean this with respect, but stackoverflow is not a place to learn how to program. Please look into an online class or book or something for learning a new language.